# C++ printf std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, printf

How I can do something like this in C++:

```
void my_print(format_string) {
   vector<string> data;
   //Fills vector
   printf(format_string, data);
}

my_print("%1$s - %2$s - %3$s");
my_print("%3$s - %2$s);
```

I have not explained well before. The format string is entered by the application user.

In C# this works:

```
void my_print(format_string) {
 List<string> data = new List<string>();
 //Fills list
 Console.WriteLine(format_string, data.ToArray);
}

my_print("{0} - {1} - {2}");
my_print("{2} - {1}");
```

Comment: %1$s print the first string, %2$s the second and so on...

Comment: C# has introspection, C++ doesn't (at least not out of the box), so you can't just print arbitrary objects. You have to add more context like wether you only need to output `string` objects etc.

Comment: I assume his arrays have a potentially variable number of elements.

Comment: @Ken: Yes and the format string can change.

Comment: @Sebtm, please accept an answer so we can find out what solution you wound up choosing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have temporarly solved with this function:

```
string format_vector(string format, vector<string> &items)
{   
   int counter = 1;

   replace_string(format,"\\n","\n");
   replace_string(format,"\\t","\t");

   for(vector<string>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it) {
        ostringstream stm; stm << counter;
        replace_string(format, "%" + stm.str(), *it);
        counter++;
   }
    return format;
}
```

Comment: I think that's a pretty reasonable solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
printf("%s - %s - %s", data[0].c_str(), data[1].c_str(), data[2].c_str() );
```

Note that you must convert to C-style strings - printf cannot do this for you.

**Edit:** In response to your revised question, I think you will have to parse the format string yourself, as you will have to validate it. printf() won't do the job.

Answer (score 10):

If you're going to use streams, you can also use `ostream_iterator` in conjunction with a looping construct like `copy`:

```
vector<string> data;
data.assign(10, "hello");

copy( &data[0], &data[3], ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
```

Note that the second parameter to `copy` points to one past the end.  Output:

> hello hello hello

Comment: But the output the OP wanted was "hello - hello - hello"

Comment: `ostream_iterator` doesn't do the job here. It appends the delimiter to every write, whereas the questioner wants a separator (i.e. not appended after the last write).

Comment: @Neil & Steve:  True.  Nonetheless, this is a technique I have found many people are unfamiliar with that is useful and consise in many situations where a plain `printf` is desired.  For example, dumping debugging data to the screen.

Comment: Though it's not included in the standard, an ostream_iterator-like class that only inserts separators is entirely possible. see: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/a746a588cedfa44b

Comment: You don't want to use `&data[0]` and `&data[3]` -- the standards don't guarantee that it will work. You should use `data.begin()` and `data.end()` instead.

Comment: @Ken:  Taking the address is fine.  Dereferencing that address is not.  This has been discussed many times on SO.

Comment: @John you're right. It is safe http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.3

Answer (score 6):

The [Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) might be helpful.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main(int arc, char** argv){
   std::vector<std::string> array;
   array.push_back("Hello");
   array.push_back("word");
   array.push_back("Hello");
   array.push_back("again");
   boost::format f("%s, %s! %s %s! \n");
   f.exceptions( f.exceptions() &
     ~ ( boost::io::too_many_args_bit | boost::io::too_few_args_bit )  );

   for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i=array.begin();i!=array.end();++i){
      f = f % (*i);
   }
   std::cout << f;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to do the following:

1. Convert your `std::vector<std::string>` into a `va_list` of `char*`s
2. Pass that `va_list`, along with the user-supplied format string to `vprintf`.

I still don't know how to do step 1. (What I do know is that most higher-level languages, such as Java, Scala, and Ruby have a simple, safe, direct conversion for that. C++ doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Now suports only %...f format. You can you can expand the possibilities by changing regex expression

https://regex101.com/r/dBaolO/1

```
template<typename ... Args>
        static std::string string_format(const std::string& format, Args ... args)
        {
            int size_s = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ...) + 1; // Extra space for '\0'
            if (size_s <= 0) { throw std::runtime_error("Error during formatting."); }
            auto size = static_cast<size_t>(size_s);
            auto buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(size);
            std::snprintf(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ...);
            return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1); // We don't want the '\0' inside
        }
        
        static std::string string_format(const std::string& format, std::vector<float> args)
        {
            std::string formatted(format);
            std::string pattern = R"(\%(?:\d+\.\d+)?[f|F])";
            std::regex rx(pattern);

            int args_index = 0;
            int mismatch_offset = 0;
            for (std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(format.begin(), format.end(), rx); i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i, ++args_index) {
                std::smatch match = *i;

                auto string_value = string_format(match.str(), args.at(args_index));

                formatted.replace(match.position() + mismatch_offset, match.length(), string_value);

                mismatch_offset += string_value.length() - match.length();
            }
            
            return formatted;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Call the ones you want

```
printf("%1$s - %2$s - %3$s", date[0].c_str(), data[1].c_str(), data[2].c_str());
```